# Error 2003 with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Here is the command I enter:
mysqldump --host=ec2-107-20-94-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com --password=XXXXX --user=bill --single-transaction blink10 [products,productspriceNEW] > /data/blink10.sql

Here is what i get:
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ec2-107-20-94-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (110) when trying to connect

Already checked port for mysql is open according to my firewall, where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to authorize EC2 to accept incoming connections on 3306, in addition to configuring the firewall on your instance.

See for example http://bigtrapeze.com/2011/03/01/allow-remote-mysql-connections-to-an-aws-instance/

Alternatively, you could also open an ssh tunnel with port forwarding.
See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/

Comment: ok with the first thing, i dont have that thing to comment out of my.cnf file and when I try to open up port 3306 it says it is already opened....question with the ssh tunneling, i am trying to run this via a automated job after set up, can u create ssh tunneling within a series of command ran in a file or is it something that only works through a user and putty? -- would i just setup ssh tuneling and run the same command but replace my hostname with localhost after the tunnel is established?

Comment: Right, if you can ssh to the EC2 instance for a normal interactive session, you probably have keys set up to allow you to do this.  You can do the same thing when establishing a tunnel.  If you want it automated, you may need to create a key pair for the uid that runs your automated backup, and upload the public key to the EC2 host.

Comment: I think i messed up the syntax for the tunneling a bit, its spitting this back at me [root@domU-12-31-39-0A-61-AC etc]# bash: -L: command not found   thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you messed up the syntax.  Did you not follow the example in the blog I linked to?  What did you try?

Comment: [root@domU-12-31-39-0A-61-AC etc]# -L 3306:ec2-174-129-41-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@ec2-174-129-41-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com        I entered this and it gave me an error

Comment: You need `ssh` at the start, before the `-L`.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you in a network behind a firewall that can intercept outgoing traffic (blocking port 3306) or maybe personal firewall ?

Comment: And forgot: your user (bill) must have right privileges to access the DB you have chosen. But I think it's more about route.

Comment: port 3306 is open on both instances (for the firewall)...furthermore both instances are in the same datacenter....which is what is confusing me

Comment: That's strange. Are you able to connect with that user via `mysql -h ec2-107-20-94-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com -U bill -p` ?

Comment: it just hangs after I enter the password